# Identify a YA science fiction novel from the 70s

Tags: story-identification, novel

All I remember is that it had 3 parts, and the first part was entitled "A Perfect Warrior".  The bad guy was named Odal.  The hero was a recent graduate of a sort of police academy for outer space.  He was well-intentioned, idealistic, and a total klutz.  The story line involved telepathy and some kind of mind machine that amplified it.  Any help would be much appreciated.  The book was probably written in the late 60s or early 70s.

Comment: Closing as duplicate of a newer question because it has better answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a 1969 Ben Bova book "The Dueling Machine" that has a character named Odal and a telepathy machine.  Possible match?

It's available on Project Gutenberg here:
http://www.gutenberg.org/files/30796/30796-h/30796-h.htm

Comment: That is only the first story of the book. The klutz is Hector, who assists the main character, Dr. Leoh. "They took to the slideway. Half a second later, Hector jumped off and dashed back to the communications desk for his traveling kit. He hurried back to Leoh bumping into seven bewildered citizens of various descriptions and nearly breaking both his legs when he tripped as he ran back onto the moving slideway. He went down on his face, sprawled across two lanes moving at different speeds, and needed the assistance of several persons before he was again on his feet and standing beside Leoh."